# PHP - self form post and exit

Tags: php, forms, post, exit

I actually have multiple questions. But they are related.

First is, is it a bad practice to submit forms using self posts? Does it have any bad security issues? The reason why i decided to use self posts was because i did not want to reveal file/folder structures and server side programming language i am using.

For example, this clearly shows that i am using php and that the logout.php file is inside a logout folder on the sibling level.

```
<form action="../logout/logout.php" method="post">
   //form elements goes here
</form>
```

With this example, i don't show what server side language i am using but a programmer clearly knows that it is a self post and that the logic have to go through itself first:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['log_out']))
  {
     // do some stuff
  }
?>
<form method="post">
   //form elements goes here
</form>
```

The consequence of having a self post as i realized, is that i have to have a complicated logic at the beginning of every self post the page. These logics will have to select the right code of execution, sometimes redirect me and stop from executing the rest of the code.

For example, here i have a page that does multiple things and posts to itself. In order to stop executing the rest of the code or html bellow again i need use the php function "exit".

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['add_two_numbers']))
  {
     // code for adding two numbers
     exit();
  }
  else if (isset($_POST['add_three_numbers']))
  {
     // code for adding three numbers
     exit();
  }
  else if (isset($_POST['log_out']))
  {
     // destroy session and data before logging out
     header("location: ./logout/logout.php");
     exit();
  }

  // php code that should happen if there is no post logic and
  // will be unapropiately executed if exit is not used
?>

<html>
  <head>
     <script>
     function init()
     {
         // will do stuff if php did not exit properly
     }

     // more js code

     window.onload = init;
```

So, i have to use php command exit which i read so much about how it causes problem and it is bad and some suggest use return instead. However, the problem with return is that it doesn't always stop the code from continue executing specially the html part. So is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you've been reading, but self posting and exiting are just fine.

Comment: _“i did not want to reveal file/folder structures and server side programming language i am using”_ – that’s a total nonsense argument. Security by Obscurity doesn’t work.

Comment: If you're trying to hide the fact that your server side language is php then the file extension is only one of many things you'll need to obscure. anyway as @CBroe says obscuring is not securing

Comment: You *could* save the logout code to an index.php in your logout folder and just send the form to the folder; but as said above, self posting and exiting are AOK, and you have a lot more things to do if you don't want anyone to know you're using PHP (and why is that a problem anyway? ... We all know that facebook, wikipedia, et al, use php).

Comment: Thank you for your replies.You guys are right that the best way to obscure the language i am using is by making the server parse php using html extension. However, there are some servers you work on that you don't have the option to configure Apache or IIS. Well, the thing about security is that i am always taught that if you can't make it 100% secure, make it 200% harder to break in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try and keep your page from loading all code at once every time, just have each main logic in a separate file that you can include and run if each element is requested.

Even keeping a one-file include option that contains all these other includes may be cleaner and easier to implement.

You would have your code pages (however you name them):

```
add.two.php
add.three.php
logout.php
default.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add_two_numbers'])) {
            require('/directory/hierarchy/add.two.php');
            exit();
        }
    elseif(isset($_POST['add_three_numbers'])) {
            require('/directory/hierarchy/add.three.php');
            // code for adding three numbers
             exit();
        }
     elseif(isset($_POST['log_out'])) {
             // destroy session and data before logging out
             header("location: ./logout/logout.php");
             exit();
         }
     else
         require('/directory/hierarchy/default.php'); ?>

<html>
  <head>
     <script>
     function init()
     {
         // will do stuff if php did not exit properly
     }

     // more js code

     window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

Self form posting in PHP is called "Sticky forms", if i can remember, which is probably fine in any way and nothing wrong with it(in my experience). I personally used sticky forms for form field validation purposes and/or to output additional information(status, errors and etc.).
To avoid exit() you probably should change your webpage logic but it's hard for to give you an advice at this moment :).